# stopped copying large number of files using FileUtils

Tags: java, fileutils, apache-commons-io

i am using library apache common io to copy file in my java program. when i tried to copy a lot of files (about 250.000) it just copied 4.454 and then stopped copying.

i saw in the task manager it's still running.

```
public void copyFiles(File source, File dest) {
    Collection<File> all = new ArrayList<File>();

    try {
        addTree(source, all);
        for (File elem : all) {
            int p = 1;
            File newFile = new File(dest.toString() + "\\" + elem.getName().replace(".", " ("+p+")."));
            if (findFile(elem.getName(), dest)) {
                for (int x = 1; newFile.exists() == true; x++) {
                    newFile = new File(dest.toString() + "\\" + elem.getName().replace(".", " ("+x+")."));
                }
                FileUtils.copyFile(elem.getAbsoluteFile(), newFile);
                // jika file TIDAK di hidden maka copy file ke direktori
            } else if (!(elem.isHidden())) {
                FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(elem, dest);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you get any exception.? Can you please share the printstack trace logs

Comment: no there is no exception. even i run it in debug mode. the console is still running. but copying file is stopped arround 4.500 files. never reaching 5.000 files.